# Subset dataframe by combination of column names in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the dataframe below:

```
DF2 = data.frame(agency_postcode = factor(rep(c(12345,45678,24124,32525,32325),2)),
                 car_group=factor(rep(c("Microcar","City car","Supermini","Compact","SUV"),2)),
                 transmission=factor(rep(c("automatic","manual"),5)))
```

and I have a shiny from which the user select one or more column names. What I want to achieve is after selecting a column name to have return all the values of the dataframe equal to the first row of this column.The same logic should be applied when more than one columns selected.So for example if I select all three columns then the first row of the dataframe must be returned instead of none.

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
                 selectInput("sel","Filter by:",
                             choices = colnames(DF2),
                             multiple=T,selected = "agency_postcode")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("D")

    )
  )
)
#server.r
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$D<-renderDataTable({
    DE<-DF2[ which(DF2[,input$sel] %in% DF2[1, input$sel]), ]
    datatable(DE)
  })

}
```

Comment: What is the criteria when you select 2 columns

Comment: I want to find the rows which have the value of the first row for every selected column

Comment: In that case, just do `DF2[1, input$sel]`

Comment: it works but I get 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix) when I select only one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to specify the rowindex, column name (or column index) and `drop` to take care off cases to avoid simplifying the dimensions from data.frame to `vector` for single column, single row cases as by default (`drop = TRUE`) if we check `?Extract`

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
>
> drop - For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further details.

```
DE <- DF2[1, input$sel, drop = FALSE]
```

---

With the change, the app works fine

[image]

Comment: I will give you that since it answers this Q but Im going to post a differennt case and post the link in the comments here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961775/subset-a-dataframe-based-on-columns-of-another-dataframe-in-a-shiny-app