# Subset a dataframe based on columns of another dataframe in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have the dataframe below:

```
DF2 = data.frame(agency_postcode = factor(rep(c(12345,45678,24124,32525,32325),2)),
                 car_group=factor(rep(c("Microcar","City car","Supermini","Compact","SUV"),2)),
                 transmission=factor(rep(c("automatic","manual"),5)))
```

which I use and display as rhandsontable in order to create a second table. First you are supposed to select one or more options from filter by input and then a level from the selected filter(s). Then you press search. What I basically want to do is subset the second table based on the first row of every selected column of the first table. The issue is in line 30 of server.r in which I should give the `input$sel`

```
#ui.r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width=2,
                 selectInput("sel","Filter by:",
                             choices = c("agency_postcode","date_start","days","car_group","transmission","driver_age"),
                             multiple=T,selected = "agency_postcode"),
                 actionButton("sr","Search")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(4,offset = 0, style='padding:0px;',rHandsontableOutput("hot")),
        column(8,offset = 0, style='padding:0px;',rHandsontableOutput("hot2"))

      )

    )
  )
)
#server.r
#server.r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(jsonlite)
server <- function(input, output) {

  #Create rhandsontable as a reactive expression
  DFR2<-reactive({

    rhandsontable(DF2[1,1:2], rowHeaders = NULL,height = 200)%>%
      hot_col(colnames(DF2)[1:2])   
  })

  #Display the rhandsontable
  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({

    DFR2()

  })

  #Convert the rhandsontable to a daraframe
  DFR3<-reactive({
    req(input$hot)
    hot_to_r(input$hot)
  })
  #Subset the initial dataframe by value of the 1st row-1st column cell of DF3
  DFR4 <- reactive({

    req(DFR3())
    D<-DF2[ which(DF2[,1] %in% DFR3()[1, 1]), ] #input$sel is supposed to be used here instead of 1
    for(i in 1:ncol(D)){
      D[,i] <- factor(D[,i])
    }
    D
  })
  #Display the new rhandsontable
  output$hot2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    input$sr
    isolate(rhandsontable(DFR4()[1,], rowHeaders = NULL,height = 200)%>%
              hot_col(colnames(DFR4())) )  


  })


}
```

Comment: We are missing some code for selecting levels for filter. And, more importantly, an example of what would the second table look like based on `input$sel`. From the current description, I understand the following. To get the second table, you want to filter the first table to keep the first element of every selected column. For such two table manipulations it might be better to use `join` functions rather than filtering. You create a small table based on user inputs, and then use something like `dplyr::inner_join` to extract rows from a large table that match entries in the smaller table.

Comment: could you add a solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Here is an app that uses a small table to filter a larger one using `inner_join`. I am not sure this will match the design you had in mind. It is still unclear to me where the filter levels are coming from, or what the hands on tables are for. But you should be able to adapt this approach to your design. Note also that I am not using hands on tables. A direct replacement of the calls to `renderTable` with `renderRHandsontable` should work too.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

sub_cars <- mtcars[, c("cyl", "gear", "am")]

ui <- fluidPage(
  column(width=3,
         selectInput(
    inputId = "sel_col",
    label = "Select variables",
    multiple = TRUE,
    choices = c("cyl", "gear", "am"),
    selectize = TRUE),
    uiOutput("cyl"),
    uiOutput("gear"),
    uiOutput("am")
    ),
  column(width = 3, 
         tableOutput("filter_table")),
  column(width = 6,
         tableOutput("large_table"))

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$cyl <- renderUI({
    if ("cyl" %in% input$sel_col) {
      selectInput(
        inputId = "sel_cyl",
        label = "Select cylinders",
        choices = unique(sub_cars$cyl),
        multiple = TRUE,
        selectize = TRUE
      )
    }
  })    
    output$gear <- renderUI({
      if ("gear" %in% input$sel_col) {
        selectInput(
          inputId = "sel_gear",
          label = "Select gears",
          choices = unique(sub_cars$gear),
          multiple = TRUE,
          selectize = TRUE
        )
      }
    })
    output$am <- renderUI({
      if ("am" %in% input$sel_col) {
        selectInput(
          inputId = "sel_am",
          label = "Select am",
          choices = unique(sub_cars$am),
          multiple = TRUE,
          selectize = TRUE
        )
      }
    })

    # make a small filter table
    filter_df <- reactive({
      validate(
        need(!is_null(input$sel_col),
             message = "Please select a column"))
      cols <- input$sel_col
      cols_vals <- map(cols, function(x) input[[paste0("sel_", x, collapse="")]])

      df <- map2_dfr(cols, cols_vals, function(x, y)
        filter(sub_cars,!!as.name(x) %in% y)) %>% 
        select(one_of(cols)) %>% 
        distinct()

      return(df)
    })

    output$filter_table <- renderTable({
      validate(
        need(nrow(filter_df()) > 0,
             message = "Please select filter values"))
      filter_df()
      })

    # inner join the larger table
    large_df <- reactive({
      validate(
        need(nrow(filter_df()) > 0,
             message = "Please select filter values"))
      cols <- input$sel_col
      inner_join(x=filter_df(), y=mtcars, by = cols)
    })

    output$large_table <- renderTable({large_df()})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is a gif of what it does.

[image]